# Authentication issue with the Desire2Learn GettingStarted sample site

Tags: desire2learn

I'm trying to test out the GettingStarted sample site with our LE instance but when I authenticate to my instance, I'm never redirected back to the sample site. This is not the case if I use the D2L provided sample site and login. 
My steps:
- Open the sample site
- Update the fields
- Click on Authenticate
- Login to my D2L instance
- Never redirected back to the sample site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would verify the key you are using in the sample is present in the Manage Extensibility screen. More information on reviewing that is available at http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/admin/manage.html

(App Keys are typically limited to a particular domain and the key with the samples are limited to the sample site).

Comment: Thanks Cadmium. I verified the domain name for my key matches my LE address. I also verified the key is not in the Manage Extensibility page. My guess is the LE is not configured to sync with the Key Tool Service. I have opened up a support request with D2L Support.